# Graph API - Photo uploaded by API is not visible

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

I`m geting the following problem.

Using graph api I can create an album (exactly photo album of my app). There is no problem also to upload photo to already created album (I have aid of this album as result of previous operation). After uploading photo I get also pid of the photo.

The problem starts now at the moment when I would like to get photos of the album. Graph API returns an empty array. Also I don't see any new album when I go to app page. However if I go to wall of my app page, I see this photo on "last added photos" list. I can enlarge uploaded photo, and I even see info that it's located in the proper album. There is another wird thing. If I choose this album, Facebook notice me that it`s an empty album.

I doesn't mean those operations are not done well, because if I request for a particular photo using pid (which I know from upload photo operation) I get a proper result - photo exist. Unfortunately it's really uncomfortable to store all pids of album in data base and perform separated request to each of it.

Comment: Is there another album with the name "YOURFACEBOOKAPPNAME" + "Photos"? Is the photo in that album?

Comment: No, there is no more albums on this page. If I go to app page, FB notice me there is no albums, and photos. However on the wall you can see the photos were added.

Comment: There is one more thing I just noticed. I can request (by GraphAPI) for one of the uploaded photos. There is given an author id of the photo (exactly AppID). So photo is created by this app, but when I do GraphAPI request "APP_ID/photos" I revive an empty array.

Comment: I think its time to post some code, @michaltaberski. What you are describing is indeed strange.

Answer (score 4):

If the Facebook App is in "sandbox" mode, the images will only be visible to the admin/developers/tester users. Public users will not see the images.

Turning sandbox mode off fixed this issue for me.